# command.ExecuteScalar is not returning the value I know exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, executescalar

I have tried various ways of doing this, but none seems to work. The routine keeps returning 0 as result is null.

This is my code:

```
string strSql = "SELECT [ID] FROM [PurchaseOrder].[dbo].[FMSSupplier] where (ExternalRef = @ExternalRef) and (CompanyID = @CompanyID)";

try
{
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql);
     command.Connection = new SqlConnection(PO_ConnectionString);
     command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExternalRef",SqlDbType.NVarChar ,50){Value = strExternalRef});
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = intCompanyID });
     if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) command.Connection.Open();
     var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
     if (result != null)
     {
         return (int)result;
     }
     else
     {
         return 0;
     }
}
```

I have tested this in SQL Server, the record exists:

```
SELECT [ID] 
FROM [PurchaseOrder].[dbo].[FMSSupplier] 
WHERE (ExternalRef = 'EDE01') and (CompanyID = 24)
```

The record ID is NOT zero, and the ConnectionString works in other instances.

These are the values of my two parameters:
CompanyID = 24
strExternalRef = EDE01

Comment: Is your connection string correct?

Comment: where in your code do you set intCompanyID , strExternalRef values??

Comment: Is there a `catch` block?  Could an exception be thrown?

Comment: As @ewitkows suggests, I would verify the connection string, including the possibility that it may be changed at run time. Include `@@SERVERNAME` in the sql statement, debug, and verify.  ie `"SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS [ServerName], [ID] FROM [PurchaseOrder].[dbo].[FMSSupplier] where (ExternalRef = @ExternalRef) and (CompanyID = @CompanyID)";`

Comment: Make sure you close your connection after you are done with it. Also you can clean up your code by using command.Parameters.AddWithValue().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and most important, the check

```
 if (command.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) command.Connection.Open();
```

Doesn't guarrantue that the connection will open. Why?

State can be:

```
    Broken
    Connecting
    //..etc
```

Secondly I dont know if you assign a value to  `intCompanyID , strExternalRef` values (maybe you do in snippet you dont show to us)...

Any way try if this work as a first debug step:

```
   try
    {
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql);
         command.Connection = new SqlConnection(PO_ConnectionString);
         command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExternalRef",SqlDbType.NVarChar ,50){Value ="EDE01"});
         command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 24});
         command.Connection.Open();
         var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
         if (result != null)
         {
             return (int)result;
         }
         else
         {
             return 0;
         }
}

 catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: thanks apomene. Tried the change. The connection.open made no difference, but changing the way those parameter values were set did. The literal valuees worked. Any idea why?

Comment: I think strExternal ref needs trimming. My code worked after this: command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExternalRef",SqlDbType .NVarChar ,50){Value = strExternalRef .Trim ()});

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your parameter is using the same SqlDbType as the database column is using. In my case I was setting the command parameter with SqlDbType.VarChar when the related database column was using NVarChar.